# possible implementations of casting in c++

Tags: c++

I have this snippet of the code in my `header`:

```
class A {
private:
    int player;
public:
    A(int initPlayer = 0);
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
    ~A();
    void foo() const;
friend int operator==(const A& i, const A& member) const;
};
```

#### implementation of the operator==

```
int operator==(const A& i, const A& member) const{
    if(i.player == member.player){
        return  1;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

and I need casting for this part of my code:

i - is some int, which my function receives

A *pa1 = new A(a2);

```
assert(i == *pa1);
```

I receive an error `non-member function`, How can I fix it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is nothing to do with casting or user-defined conversions.

You can't have a const qualification on a function that isn't a member function so this:

```
int operator==(const A& i, const A& member) const;
```

should be this:

```
int operator==(const A& i, const A& member);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the const qualifier from the friend function. Friend functions are not member functions hence the const qualifier is meaningless.