# conversions in C++

Tags: c++

I have this snippet of the code:

#### header

```
class A {
private:
    int player;
public:
    A(int initPlayer = 0);
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
    ~A();
    void foo() const;
friend A& operator=(A& i, const A& member);
};
```

#### operator=

```
A& operator=(A& i, const A& member){   
    i(member.player);
    return i;
}
```

and I have row in my code:

```
 i = *pa1;
```

A *pa1 = new A(a2);
at the beginning i was int

how can I fix it, thanks in advance
I have an error `must be non-static function`

Comment: You should really not repost questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043219/). There is an edit-function if you have new or other problems in the same code.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment operator for a class must be a member function, not a friend.

```
A& operator=( const A& member){   
    this->player = member.player);
    return *this;
}
```

If you want to convert an A class object to an integer, provide a named conversion function such as ToInt().

As with all your questions, this could easily have been answered by reading a C++ text book. This is the last of such questions from you I will be answering.

Comment: at the beginning 'i' is an integer, I want to convert it to my class, how can I do it?

Comment: as I know it doesn't work both sides, I can write *pa1=i, my question is, can I write i=*pa1?

Comment: @lego69 - Read up on conversion member functions.  It is possible to define something like `operator int() const` as a member function and your class gains an automatic conversion to `int`.  It's generally not recommended though.  Automatic conversions can very quickly render code unreadable.